# Conditional independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have three events A,B and C and I have the following relationship:

```
P(A|B,C) = P(A|B) P(A|C)
```

Does this imply that event B and C are conditionally independent given A?

Answer (score 0):

You have, from given condition, $P(BC\mid A)=\frac{P(ABC)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(AB)P(BC)P(CA)}{P(A)P(B)P(C)}\ne \frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}\cdot\frac{P(CA)}{P(A)}$, in general.

Comment: How did you go from \frac{P(ABC)}{P(A)} to \frac{P(AB)P(BC)P(CA)}{P(A)P(B)P(C)} ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of conditional probability and some algebraic manipulation of the original identity we find.
$\begin{align}
\tag{1} {\sf P}(A\mid B, C) &= {\sf P}(A\mid B){\sf P}(A\mid C)
\\
\tag{2} {\sf P}(A, B, C)/{\sf P}(B, C) & = {\sf P}(A, B) {\sf P}(A, C) / {\sf P}(B) {\sf P}(C)
\\
\tag{3} {\sf P}(B, C\mid A){\sf P}(A)/{\sf P}(B, C) & = {\sf P}(A, B) {\sf P}(A, C) / {\sf P}(B) {\sf P}(C)
\\
\tag{4} {\sf P}(B, C\mid A)& = {\sf P}(A, B) {\sf P}(A, C) {\sf P}(B, C)/ {\sf P}(A) {\sf P}(B) {\sf P}(C)
\\
\tag{5} {\sf P}(B, C\mid A)& = {\sf P}(B\mid A) {\sf P}(C\mid A)\times{\sf P}(A) {\sf P}(B, C)/ {\sf P}(B) {\sf P}(C)
\end{align}$

Since ${\sf P}(A) {\sf P}(B, C)/ {\sf P}(B) {\sf P}(C)$ is not generally equal to $1$, then we do not necessarily have conditional independence of $B$ and $C$ given $A$.